# C# in Depth: Does it have any forum?

Tags: c#

Do you know Where can I find an active  forum related to book "C# in Depth" by Jon Skeet?

Comment: I think you are in the forum already ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For asking a question which is really specific to the book itself (release dates, reporting errata etc) the Manning Forum is probably most appropriate ([first edition](http://www.manning-sandbox.com/forum.jspa?forumID=352), [second edition](http://www.manning-sandbox.com/forum.jspa?forumID=569)).

If you're asking a question about C# itself which occurred to you while reading the book, asking a question here is probably the best bet.

If you just want to let me know what you thought of the book, you can mail me directly (skeet@pobox.com).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.manning-sandbox.com/forum.jspa?forumID=352

But right here on Stack Overflow is a really close runner up...

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's at manning publications:

It's for updated second edition :

http://www.manning-sandbox.com/forum.jspa?forumID=569